# Scala Higher order functions in details

Tags: scala, higher-order-functions

I am learning Scala Higher Order Functions. I am studying [an example](https://github.com/msumit/Scala-Coursera/blob/master/Week%203%20-%20Data%20and%20Abstraction/TweetSet.scala) that is a class; there is one method that receives a function and a value parameter and returns a value. The function is `p: Tweet => Boolean` and the method implementation is further below. I want to know where is the implementation of the p function.

```
class NonEmpty(elem: Tweet, left: TweetSet, right: TweetSet) extends TweetSet {
  def filterAcc(p: Tweet => Boolean, acc: TweetSet): TweetSet = {
    if (p(elem)) {
      left.filterAcc(p, acc.incl(elem))
      right.filterAcc(p, acc.incl(elem))  
    } else {
        left.filterAcc(p, acc)
        right.filterAcc(p, acc)
    }                    
}
```

Comment: I understand it might be more disturbing when the parameter is a function, but your question is in fact exactly the same as "what is the value of the `acc` parameter?". It is whatever is passed as `acc` when `filterAcc` is called. Same for `p`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wonder to know where is the implementation of the p function

If you go further down in the class definition, you'll see one of the implementations of `p` in [`union`](https://github.com/msumit/Scala-Coursera/blob/master/Week%203%20-%20Data%20and%20Abstraction/TweetSet.scala#L181)

```
def union(that: TweetSet): TweetSet = {
  this.filterAcc(elem => true, that)
}
```

With Higher Order Functions, the caller of the method is the one in charge of providing an implementation of the function that he wishes to run. You can take a look at common use cases such as `map`, `flatMap`, `filter`, etc on Scalas collection library.

Comment: so for filterAcc function inside the union function, all p(elem) will return true? No matters which elem is?

Comment: @FelipeOliveiraGutierrez Yup, for that function specifically. You can provide any implementation you desire.